# Flutter Webview The photo selection screen does not appear on the site I refer

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, flutter-layout

I am redirected to a site using webview. A photo needs to be selected on the site I reference, but when I call the site with webview, this selection screen does not appear. How can i fix that?

[image]

Here is my android-manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) work for me

Here is my code:

```
  WebviewScaffold(
  url: 'www.google.com',
  withLocalStorage: true, //for upload files
);
```